# Scale color gradient to reflect edge weight in network

Tags: r, networking, visualization

I am plotting a network where the edges have designated weight (i.e., the number of times that path occurs in the network). I'd like to reflect the weight of the edges by assigning a color gradient where black represents the highest weight and light grey represents the lowest weight. Every value in between max/min would have an assigned value where the same weight would be assigned the same color.

I have a prelim code written out, but after double checking, it seems that this did not work. Would anyone have an idea of where this went wrong?

```
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "lightgray"))
my.palette <- rev(colfunc(length(unique(E(net)$weight))))
E(net)$color <- my.palette[rev(order(E(net)$weight))]

plot(net, layout = l, edge.curved = 0.25, vertex.size = V(net)$size*0.3, vertex.frame.color = V(net)$color_quartile, edge.arrow.size = 0.1)
```